# Why Use of Undeclared type after changing name of ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a ios Project that was running fine. I changed the name of a VC to HomeVC and now I get "Use of undeclared type HomeVC"? I am guessing renaming a VC in xCode is still an issue after 4 years (why I left xcode ios back then)?

HomeVC.swift

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class HomeVC: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBAction func actionButtonWasPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        actionButton.animateButton(shouldLoad: true, withMessage: nil)
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    @IBOutlet weak var actionButton: RoundedShadowButton!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        mapView.delegate = self
    }
}
```

ContainerVC.swift where bug is

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore


class ContainerVC: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}

private extension UIStoryboard {

     class func mainStoryBoard() -> UIStoryboard {
         return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
     }

     class func leftViewController() -> LeftSidePanelVC? {
         return mainStoryBoard().instantiateViewController(identifier: "LeftSidePanelVC") as? LeftSidePanelVC
     }

     class func homeVC() -> HomeVC? {  <--- where its complaining?
         return mainStoryBoard().instantiateViewController(identifier: "HomeVC") as? HomeVC
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately sometimes Xcode needs a manual help.

Try these in order to fix:

- Make a fresh build
- Clean Build
- Delete drived data
- Restart Xcode

<sub>. It should be fixed by here but you can also try restarting your mac.</sub>

Comment: Followed the normal path to DerivedData but doesn't appear to be in library/developer/...

Comment: Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations. Then you can find the true path

Comment: I noticed there is an R next to the file in the project navigator?